# How to get sale and event tracking reports for Mobile Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush

We left Urban Airship for push notifications to Salesforce Mobile Push.  With Urban Airship we were able to get reports on
- app open
- added to cart
- purchased (conversion, AOV, purchase total)

We wanted to track the same with Salesforce. Is there a way we can add this into our app to get this information without adding a 3rd party vendor to track links like Appsflyer, Branch.io or Mparticle?

Answer (score 2):

These features are available with the Marketing Cloud via Predictive Intelligence (PI) Analytics.  Please discuss this feature with your account manager and/or your success engineer.

Android: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/features/analytics.html

iOS: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/personalization-collect.html

Comment: Updated Links: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/personalization-collect.html

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html